# GRASS r.mapcalc to replace null values

Tags: raster, grass-gis, overlay, r.mapcalc

Is there a way to use r.mapcalc to replace null with 0?

I tried `if(isnull(map1), 0)` but that produces a map that is entirely 0. I need only cells containing null to be altered!

Comment: HelloWorld, Hi. Can you try with: `if(isnull(map1), 0, map1)` ?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thank you very much that worked! :) Can you tell I'm new? Write an answer and Ill accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following documentation: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.mapcalc.html.

> - The function isnull() returns 1 if its argument is NULL and 0 otherwise
> - if(x,a) returns:
>     NULL if *x* is NULL; *a* if *x* is non-zero; *0* otherwise
> - if(x,a,b) returns:
>     NULL if *x* is NULL; *a* if *x* is non-zero; *b* otherwise

If the value of the pixel in *map1* is *NULL*, `isnull(map1)` returns *1*. Otherwise returns *0*.

As `isnull(map1)` returns non-zero (*1*) for *NULL* values in *map1*, `if(isnull(map1), 0)` returns *0*. Otherwise returns *0*, too.

So, we need a third argument:

- As `isnull(map1)` returns non-zero (*1*) for *NULL* values in *map1*, `if(isnull(map1), 0, map1)` returns *0*. Otherwise returns *map1* value.

---

Seems to me that there are some ways to implement the same logic.

But following your expression, `if(isnull(map1), 0, map1)` can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I would point out that GRASS has a special module for dealing with null values: `r.null`. You could set your null pixels to zero by running:

```
r.null map1 null=0
```